# enter key to follow the tabindex (in scenario where enter key is changed to behave as tab)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a 3x3 table within a form. By default tab key moves the cursor in horizontal directions on these input fields. When a tabindex is given ( Like in the example below) the tab key moves cursor columns wise instead of row wise, as I needed.

With various sources from SO answers, I came up with the Jquery to use enter key as tab. But, could not figure out how to follow the tabindex as achieved above , i.e by pressing enter key instead of cursor moving row-wise, i want it to move in column wise. Below is what I have so far, any help is appreciated.

Demo of how it currently works. http://jsfiddle.net/unCu5/125/

Source of below code: [jquery how to catch enter key and change event to tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2335553/jquery-how-to-catch-enter-key-and-change-event-to-tab)

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><input tabindex="1" placeholder="1" /></td>
        <td><input tabindex="2" placeholder="2" /></td>
        <td><input tabindex="3" placeholder="3" /></td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td><input tabindex="1" placeholder="1" /></td>
        <td><input tabindex="2" placeholder="2" /></td>
        <td><input tabindex="3" placeholder="3" /></td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td><input tabindex="1" placeholder="1" /></td>
        <td><input tabindex="2" placeholder="2" /></td>
        <td><input tabindex="3" placeholder="3" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>

$('input').live("keypress", function(e) {
  /* ENTER PRESSED*/
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    /* FOCUS ELEMENT */
    var inputs = $(this).parents("form").eq(0).find(":input");
    var idx = inputs.index(this);

    if (idx == inputs.length - 1) {
      inputs[0].select()
    } else {
      inputs[idx + 1].focus(); //  handles submit buttons
      inputs[idx + 1].select();
    }
    return false;
  }
})
```

@Dekel solution work for the html scenario he displayed, but I have a different type of HTML on view source. How do I fix this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery how to catch enter key and change event to tab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2335553/jquery-how-to-catch-enter-key-and-change-event-to-tab)

Comment: @Dekel, my Q is not how to change enter key to tab. I already solved it in the given code above. But, i want that enter key to follow tabindex provided to each input. By default, the enter key moves horizontally ( row-wise) for input fields ( let says for a 3x3 table), But, I want the cursor to move column-wise. So, how to change the default behaviour in JS here ?

Comment: Sorry, now it's more clear :)

Comment: put jsfiddle.net DEMO , then , we can figure out yr pb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of just focus the next `input` element, you can find the next element (based on the tabindex) and focus on him:

```
$('input[tabindex^="2"]');
```

Check this example:

```js
$(document).ready(function () { // Will only run once the page Document Object Model (DOM) is ready for JavaScript code 
    // Create a jQuery object containing the html element 'input'
    // Create a .not() method to exclude buttons for keypress event
    $(":input:not(:disabled)").not($(":button")).keypress(function(evt) {
        // If the keypress event code is 13 (Enter)
        if (evt.keyCode == 13) {
            // get the attribute type and if the type is not submit
            itype = $(this).prop('type');
            if (itype !== 'submit') {
                currentTabindex = $(this).attr('tabindex');
                if (currentTabindex) {
                    nextInput = $('input[tabindex^="'+ (parseInt(currentTabindex)+1) +'"]');
                    if (nextInput.length) {
                        nextInput.focus();
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><input tabindex="1" placeholder="1" /></td>
        <td><input tabindex="4" placeholder="4" /></td>
        <td><input tabindex="7" placeholder="7" /></td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td><input tabindex="2" placeholder="2" /></td>
        <td><input tabindex="5" placeholder="5" /></td>
        <td><input tabindex="8" placeholder="8" /></td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td><input tabindex="3" placeholder="3" /></td>
        <td><input tabindex="6" placeholder="6" /></td>
        <td><input tabindex="9" placeholder="9" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

> The code doesn't support go back from the last input to the first. You will need to write it explicitly.

## Updated version - fix wrong `tabindex` values

The original question didn't mention that `tabindex` could repeat or don't have sequential values.
This code will "fix" the values of `tabindex` based on the order in the code AND the values of the `tabindex`. It will support both repeated tabindex values and non sequential values (1, 2, 3, 6, 7):

```js
function fixTabIndex() {
    // Find all inputs. Their order will be the same order they appear inside your html.
    inputs = $('input');
    // Save the original HTML order of the inputs (we need this to compare their order in the HTML in case or equal two tabindex 
    inputs_original = $('input');
    
    // Sort the inputs by their tabindex values and their position in the DOM
    // More info on Array.prototype.sort: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort
    inputs.sort(function(a, b) {
        if ($(a).attr('tabindex') == $(b).attr('tabindex')) {
            // If tabindex is equal - sort by the position in the DOM
            if (inputs_original.index(a) < inputs_original.index(b)) {
                return -1;
            } else {
                return 1;
            }
        } else if ($(a).attr('tabindex') < $(b).attr('tabindex')) {
            return -1;
        } else {
            return 1;
        }
    });
    // Set the new value of the tabindex based on the position in the sorted array
    inputs.each(function(i, el) {
        $(el).attr('tabindex', i+1);
    });
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    // First we need to fix the tabindex values:
    fixTabIndex();
    $("input").keypress(function(evt) {
        // If the keypress event code is 13 (Enter)
        if (evt.keyCode == 13) {
            // Make sure this is not a submit input
            if ($(this).prop('type') !== 'submit') {
                currentTabindex = $(this).attr('tabindex');
                if (currentTabindex) {
                    nextInput = $('input[tabindex^="'+ (parseInt(currentTabindex)+1) +'"]');
                    if (nextInput.length) {
                        nextInput.focus();
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td><input tabindex="1" placeholder="1" /></td>
        <td><input tabindex="2" placeholder="2" /></td>
        <td><input tabindex="3" placeholder="3" /></td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td><input tabindex="1" placeholder="1" /></td>
        <td><input tabindex="2" placeholder="2" /></td>
        <td><input tabindex="3" placeholder="3" /></td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td><input tabindex="1" placeholder="1" /></td>
        <td><input tabindex="2" placeholder="2" /></td>
        <td><input tabindex="3" placeholder="3" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion, what I noticed it by enter the cursor moves to the last row of second column in my original code. Need to figure out why. My table is inside a form, does that matter ?

Comment: You just didn't use the HTML I provided. Note the usage of the different `tabindex` in my table vs your table.

Comment: @user5249203, did you run the code snippet from my answer?

Comment: Are looking for LTR or for RTL solution? on my example when you put the cursor on the top-left input and click enter - the cursor will go to the middle-left input (the input that exists under last one).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117858/discussion-between-user5249203-and-dekel).

Comment: Can you add comments to explain the function. Today morning I tried implementing your function solution. It works column wise, but moves 2 columns ahead and then back on every enter key. Trying to solve it.. so if you can explain the code a bit I can fix it.

Comment: Added some comments and also fixed some bug in the sorting function. Check the new code there.